# How to solve $\int\frac{4y+3}{4y^2-9}dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

For an assignment from my book I have to evaluate:
$$ \int\frac{4y+3}{4y^2-9}dy $$
(and therefore actually solve it), but I don't know how to start. Thanks in advance for your help!

For your information, I know the basic principles of the methods partial fractions, short / long division and completing the square.

Comment: If you know partial fractuon, did you try to factorize the denominator?

Comment: $$4y^2-9=(2y-3)(2y+3)\;\ldots$$

Comment: The integral is $\frac12\int\frac{8y}{4y^2-9}dy+\frac34\int\frac{dy}{y^2-(3/2)^2}$. Solve the first term by setting $4y^2-9=u$. Solve the second term by using partial fractions or directly use this [standard formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089519/how-does-one-integrate-int-frac1x2-a2dx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\dfrac{4y+3}{(2y)^2-3^2}=\dfrac a{2y-3}+\dfrac b{2y+3}$$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants

$$\implies4y+3=a(2y+3)+b(2y-3)=2(a+b)y+3(a-b)$$

Compare the constants & the coefficients of $y$ to find $a,b$